# WordPress Single Sign On using SSP and ADFS as IdP proxy

Tags: wordpress, single-sign-on, windows-server-2012-r2, simplesamlphp, adfs3.0

I have configured Windows 2012 r2 with ADFS 3.0, bitnami WordPress (4.2.2) with SAML 2.0 Single Sign on plugin and Ubuntu server with SimpleSAMLphp 1.13.

WordPress configuration looks like this:

WordPress NameID policy:
[image: WordPress NameID policy]

WordPress attributes:
[image: WordPress attributes]

For authentication source I am using SSP's file module. It has attributes:

`User-Name` for user id, `mail` for user's email-address and `Filter-Id` for user's group.

At ADFS side, I have configured claims provider trust as SSP and relying party's trust as WP.

**Claim rules for those are:**

**SSP:**

*Rule 1: To transform name id policy. If this rule is not set WP's SSP gives NameIDPolicy invalid error.*

`c:[Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier", Properties["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/format"] == "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress"] => issue(Type = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name", Issuer = c.Issuer, OriginalIssuer = c.OriginalIssuer, Value = c.Value, ValueType = c.ValueType);`

*Rule 2: Pass all the claims*

`c:[Type == "https://example.com/simplesamlphp/saml2/idp/metadata.php"] => issue(claim = c);`

**WordPress:**

*Rule 1: Convert name attribute to WP's attribute*

`c:[Type == "User-Name"] => add(Type = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname", Value = c.Value);`

*Rule 2: Convert mail attribute*

`c:[Type == "mail"] => add(Type = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/emailaddress", Value = c.Value);`

*Rule 3: Convert group attribute*

`c:[Type == "Filter-Id"] => add(Type = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/Group", Value = c.Value);`

*Rule 4: Convert to Givenname attribute*

`c:[Type == "User-Name"] => add(Type = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/givenname", Value = c.Value);`

*Rule 5: Convert to Surname attribute*

`c:[Type == "User-Name"] => add(Type = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/surname", Value = c.Value);`

*Rule 6: Convert Name id policy & issue all claims*

`c:[Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name"] => issue(Type = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier", Issuer = c.Issuer, OriginalIssuer = c.OriginalIssuer, Value = c.Value, ValueType = c.ValueType, Properties["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/format"] = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress");`

User gets authenticated fine (SP/IdP-Initiated). But at WP side I get error saying `Username was not provided`.

ADFS tracer log shows me `SSO token is null or empty. Cannot write SSO token to Cookies.`

I checked IdP for user login and it shows user logged in. Tracer log also shows `Valid assertion returned from 'https://example.com/simplesamlphp/saml2/idp/metadata.php'`

I guess there is something wrong with claims rules, but I am not sure because configuration looks and works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the chain is WP --> ADFS --> SSP

Normally for NameID, you use a transform rule e.g.

Transform email to NameID with a format of email.

For the CP, you need pass-through rules for each attribute.

This rule "c:[Type == "https://example.com/simplesamlphp/saml2/idp/metadata.php"]
 => issue(claim = c);" does not pass-through all rules - best to do them individually.

The RP rules look right but the NameID rule has a format of email so it should be derived from email, not name.

Comment: Thanks. That did work. One more thing. I am trying to use same setup for OWA also. I configured OWA RP rules as: Primary sid- `c:[Type == "User-Name", Issuer == "https://example.com/simplesamlphp/saml2/idp/metadata.php"] => issue(Type = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/primarysid",  Value = c.Value);` and UPN: `c:[Type == "mail", Issuer == "https://example.com/simplesamlphp/saml2/idp/metadata.php"]
 => issue(Type = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn", Value = c.Value);`. But it shows me `upnClaimMissing` error. Can this setup be used for OWA?

Comment: No idea about OWA but metadata.php strikes me as being the actual metadata i.e. a XMl document not a claim. What's in it?

Comment: I am not that much familiar with internal working but from code it seems it provides metadata for idp. But not actual XML document. I have looked on internet for demos & every one of them showed me to configure `Issuer` like above in case of SSP.

Comment: Thanks @nzpcmad. I resolved the issue. I think there was some error with configuration. Now I have set the rule to transform `User-Name` to `upn` only and it worked! Mission accomplished :)